# Printing strings in new line (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a strange requirement similar to:

`string a = @"test content {1} test content {2}"`

While printing this, I need the output to be

```
test content {1}

test content {2}
```

So, I tried appending `\r\n` to the string but it prints like below:

`string a = "test content {1}\r\n test content {2}\r\n"`

**Output:**

`test content {1}\r\n test content {2}\r\n`

Why is this behaviour ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Try with Environment.NewLine

Comment: Printing how, to what?

Comment: Have you tried \n by itself?

Comment: Is that the actual code? That looks like = @"..." Output....

Comment: Don't look at the debugger tooltip on the variable but click on the loupe.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you. Learnt a new thing today. For people who dont know what a `loupe` is: It is the small magnification glass near the variable name. Click that and you will see the output :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the starting `@` before your `string`.

It tells the compiler to escape the `string` following, so in fact it is this:

```
string s = "test content {1}\\r\\ntest content {2}"
```

Remove the `@` and it will work.

Comment: Exactly. This worked. Either I stick with verbatim literal and use `Environment.NewLine` or to remove that as you say. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to the original string - include the linebreaks into the string, the @ is important!

```
string a = @"test content {1} 

test content {2}";
```

And the output wil be:

```
test content

test content
```

Comment: That is another good way. Didn't know that would with with literals. +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
string a = "test content {1}" + Environment.NewLine + " test content {2}" + Environment.NewLine;
```

[Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) escapes one line.

Answer (score 1):

the fact that you're using the delimiters WITHIN the string like

```
string a = "test content {1}\r\n test content {2}\r\n"
```

tells the code to handle them as a displayable string - surprise!
i'd recommend you to split the string in seperate groups, like

```
string a = "test content {1}" + Environment.NewLine + "test content {2}";
```

Comment: Your second sample doesn't even compile, and using "\n" within a strng is perfectly fine.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: yeah, sry - of course it would not compile, stupid me!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class because string are immutables

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
strb.AppendLine("test content {1}");
strb.Append("test content {2}");
string a = strb.ToString();
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, it is more elegant way thanks i will edit my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.Format() and Environment.NewLine :

`String.Format("test content {{1}}{0}test content {{2}}", Environment.NewLine)`

Double `{}` used to escape this characters. `{0}` to insert Environment.NewLine string.